# Munin ExtendedStatus option for apache mod_status is missing since enabling nginx reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, plesk, munin

I'm using munin since a long time to monitor my server (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Plesk Onyx, Apache/2.4.10, nginx/1.11.4). It worked fine with showing me all apache graphs (accesses, processes, volume).

Yesterday I installed the nginx reverse proxy on plesk to increse performance. This works fine for my website and I'm able to monitor nginx as well on munin.

But the apache graphs stopped. Because apache now listens on port 7080 I added this to munin-node.conf:

```
[apache_*]
env.url http://public-server-url:7080/server-status
env.ports 7080
```

Opening `http://public-server-url:7080/server-status` with `curl` or `lynx` works fine and I get the server status page as always.

Now I get this error when I run `munin-run apache_accesses autoconf`:

```
no (ExtendedStatus option for apache mod_status is missing on port 7080)
```

But the ExtendedStatus option is set to `On` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf`.

What did I forget? It worked fine before I added the nginx reverse proxy but this couldn't change an apache mods conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

The URL must be like `http://public-server-url:7080/server-status?auto`. Added that and now it's working fine.

Adding `?auto` to the URL does change the output of the page. Without it you get a normal website where you can see all metrics for apache. But adding `?auto` outputs just the values so it can be parsed better.

Example output:

```
Total Accesses: 30200
Total kBytes: 95000
CPULoad: .583622
Uptime: 7000
ReqPerSec: 4.20
BytesPerSec: 15800.9
BytesPerReq: 3200
BusyWorkers: 1
IdleWorkers: 99
ConnsTotal: 1
ConnsAsyncWriting: 0
ConnsAsyncKeepAlive: 0
ConnsAsyncClosing: 0
Scoreboard: _W___...
```